# generate automatically getter and setter in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, auto-generate

When I programmed with Android Studio, it seems to me that is a way to generate automatically the getter and the setter of my new java class.

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the class you want, right click anywhere in the code and chose the `Generate` option:

[image]

Then chose what you are trying to generate: setters, getters or both:

[image]

Then select the fields you want, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!